# What is the author trying to imply in this sentence? what is employment per unit of capital?

Tags: labor-economics, unemployment, policy

"The usage of extra machinery does not cause unemployment since, employment per unit of capital is large in labor-intensive products that the country exports and the vast world market allows exporting firms to operate on a large scale."

Comment: Care to offer the title of the book, page of the quotation, any context?

Comment: Also, do you have a background in macroeconomics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title of the book is "India Unlimited" by A. Panagariya. The chapter which contains this sentence is about the imprudent economic policies adopted by the Indian Govt. during the four decades after country's independence in 1947. The party which ruled India during these years formed its policies under the influence of Soviet socialism. It did not let big private firm enter into small manufactures. Author argues that big firms would have used expensive machinery and modern tech to drive growth, quality, and high productivity. New machinery would not have caused unemployment.

Comment: Good quality and high productivity would have opened avenues for big private firms in exports. The author further argues that usage of modern and costly machinery would not have caused unemployment as feared by the then policy makers. He backs his argument with the premise that "...employment per unit of capital is large in labor-intensive products that the country exports.." which I am not able to understand...Thank you for help and support. I hope the context is clear to you now.